# How to capitalize the First letter of each word in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, return, output

You are asked to ensure that the first and last names of people begin with a capital letter in their passports. For example, alison heck should be capitalised correctly as Alison Heck.

the code I've tried:

```
def solve(s):
    words = s.split()
    flag = False
    for word in words:
        if isinstance(word[0], str):
            flag = True
        else:
            flag = False
    
    if flag:
        return s.title()
    else:
        # don't know what to do

s = input()
print(solve(s))
```

this code works fine for most cases except for one,

frustrating testcase: '1 w 2 r 3g',
and the output should be '1 W 2 R 3g',
but since we are using the .title() method last 'g' will also be capitalized.

Comment: @BuddyBob Lol, that must be from the Elon family.

Comment: @BhavyaParikh if we split then we should join it back, but I couldn't maintain the exact spaces from the inputs, For Example(consider "_" this as a whitespace) :- "hello___world hi", the expected output is :- "Hello___World Hi" , but when I split and join I get something like this :- "Hello World Hi"

Comment: Yes right i didnt think about that scenario!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can try using `re.sub` here matching the pattern `\b(.)`, along with a callback function which uppercases the single letter being matched.

```py
inp = '1 w 2 r 3g'
output = re.sub(r'\b(.)', lambda x: x.group(1).upper(), inp)
print(output)  # 1 W 2 R 3g
```

Answer (score 3):

```
name = 'robert lewandowski'
print(name.title())
```

Output -

```
Robert Lewandowski
```

Answer (score 1):

#replace

def solve(s):

```
for i in s.split():
    s = s.replace(i,i.capitalize())
return s
```

In Python, the capitalize() method returns a copy of the original string and converts the first character of the string to a capital (uppercase) letter while making all other characters in the string lowercase letters.

Answer (score 0):

Check this if solves your problem

```
z=[]
s = input()
x=s.split(" ")
print(x)
for i in x:
    z.append(i.capitalize())

v=" ".join(z)
print(v)
```

Comment: The problem with this approach is, if we split then we should join it back, but I couldn't maintain the exact spaces from the inputs, For Example :- ```hello      world hi```, the expected output is :- ```Hello      World Hi``` , but when I split and join I get something like this :- "Hello World Hi"

Answer (score 0):

You can call like:

```
s = '1 w 2 r 3gH'
print(' '.join([word.capitalize() for word in s.split()]))
# 1 W 2 R 3gh
```

But note that the remaining letters also will be made in lowercase except the first letter as given in the altered example.

Answer (score 0):

You can use RE or you can try a solution like this

```
def solve(s):
    res=""
    for i in range(len(s)):
        if i==0:
           if s[i].isalpha():
               res+=s[i].capitalize()
           else:
               res+=s[i]
        else:
            if s[i].isalpha() and s[i-1]==' ':
                res+=s[i].capitalize()
            else:
                res+=s[i]
    return res
```

Answer (score -1):

if you use numpy module , then easily you can achieve the answer!
for example = Alison Heck

```
from numpy import *

answer=input("give your input").title()
print(answer)
```

this module especially made for this purpose.